# Time limit for an IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

It may sound as a dumb question. In fact, I am still thinking if that might be the cause but working with XCode and having set iOS 4.3 as my Deployment Target and iPad as my Device I am getting an unexpected error.

While running my app through the Simulator I can get it working. But when I run it through my iPad a single IBAction, fired when user taps an UIButton, that takes almost 4 minutes is not completing. In fact it's getting stopped at the same point, in a for loop.

I searched for memory leaks using XCode and it didn't find any, therefore I'm asking if there's a time limit for IBActions. I read there are 10 minutes limit for methods in background but I didn't find anything related to IBActions in foreground yet.

Comment: You could try moving the body of the method elsewhere, out of the IBAction, and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: I gotta try that. Thanks Luke.

Answer (score 0):

I think the user gets tired of waiting for a response long before the system. Normally, a button press or similar should finish after one second at most (well, maybe 1.5s), or the user thinks that the system is "slow".

Comment: I understand what u said but this is a point where the user knows it will take long. It already works this way at the other software he works and as much as we talked about it the owner/buyer of the project decided it MIGHT continue this way. Therefore I'm not here to ask whether it's a good convention or not. I'm asking if there's any limitation regarding time limit, as I read once methods in background may have a time limit up to 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for answering anyway. I guess this issue will be with me for some more days :(

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you have your button outlets properly hooked up. It is possible that it just isn't throwing the exception so you get a slow system. Put NSLog displays in your IBAction method and make sure it is executing it properly. You should be able to track it back to figure out what is going on.

Comment: They are hooked up fine. My IBAction has a for-loop and I added some NSLog inside it and in a process of 100 units, each unit takes 2 or 3 seconds. When it is processing the 69th or 70th unith it suddenly stops. No memory warnings are fired, no leaked were found and it works with the iOS/iPad Simulator. The issue happens when running at the iPad. I wonder if running through iPad is there any way to retrieve a log to see what went wrong? Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: If the action isn't absolutely necessary, you could always spit it off into a asynchronous thread. Give control back to the user while the task completes. I'd still like to know why it is taking so long to process.